# File created from base64 string causes memory leak on server

Tags: sql-server, memory-leaks, base64, ms-office, document

The company that I work for has come across a pretty significant issue with one of our releases that has brought our project to a screeching halt.

A third party application that we manage, generates word documents from base64 encoded strings stored in our SQL Server. The issue that we are having is that in some cases, when one of these documents are sent via SMTP and the file is opened by the user, the file fails to open.

When the file fails, the server locks up. The memory and cpu then grow exponentially on the server to the point that the only option is to kill the process from the server-side in order to prevent failure and down time for the rest of the users on the network.

We are using Windows 7 with Microsoft Office 2013 and the latest version of SQL Server.

What is apparent is that the word document created from the base64 string is corrupt. What isn't apparent is how this appears to bring the entire server system down in one fell swoop.

Has anyone come across this issue before and if so, what was the solution that you came up with?  We do not have access to the binaries of the 3rd party application that generates the files. We aren't able to reproduce the issue manually in order to come up with a working testcase to present to the 3rd party, so we are stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would need more details to understand your scenario. You say this is the order of events:
1. Word file is sent via SMTP (presumably an email to an Outlook client)
2. User receives email; opens attached file
3. Memory and CPU on server go to 100 percent. This creates downtime for rest of the users.
4. Need to kill this process to recover.

Since Outlook is a client-side application, it must be the Word document attachment that is causing this problem. Can you post a sample document in a public place, like a free OneDrive account? Presumably this document creates the problem. Maybe it has some VBA code? Try this with a blank document.